# what we have to do with a adsense html code

Tags: html, blogger, blogs, adsense

I have recently started a Blog, The blog is made using Blogger, Then I thought of preparing my site to show ads and then I created a Adsense account and then in the sites section I had given the URL of My Blog and after some days I saw the sites section and there was written that **needs attension**, Then I clicked on it and I found that there was wriiten a Notice and a code which I have pasted below :-

Copy and paste this code in the HTML of your site, between the  and  tags.

Your AdSense code

```
<script data-ad-client="ca-pub-4836518523777258" async src="https://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
```

Now I am Confused That where I have to add this code, In my blog theme's HTML which I have installed currently or some where else can someone tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You have actually to connect Blogger to Google AdSense. They have a direct connection, you don't need to add any code.

If you already have Google AdSense

- Go to the Earnings Tab on Blogger (top bar, in the dropdown)
- Link Your AdSense Account to your Blogger Account there
- Specify Where to Display AdSense, you'll have there 3 places to choose from
- Go to Your Blog Layout (left menu, "Layout")
- Add the AdSense Gadget
- Done! You have now ads

Comment: I have already linked my adsense to blogger, but still it says need attention, can you assist me on my mail, my mail id :- ashutoshkumarofficial1155@gmail.com